# When a user is on a subdomain in a multi-site WordPress site, create a dynamic link stays within subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, url, permalinks, cname

So I have a multi-site WordPress environment that uses the following code to direct to another product; however, when on an environment that is not the canonical (e.g. if `CNAME` is `aa.site.com`, then `ab.site.com`, `ac.stie.com`, and `ad.site.com` all use the same codebase), the link directs you to the correct product and page or post, but with the `CNAME` - where as I would like the subdomains to stay when navigating through products.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $this->get_field('page_id.ID') ); ?>" class="button">Product 2</a>
```

So far argument's sake, lets say that we are on `http://ab.site.com/product_1/`, and wish to go to `http://ab.site.com/product_2/`.  Currently, the way the site was originally set up (not my doing, I would have rewritten the get_permalink function in the links.template.php to prep for this; however, it is too late in the game to do that now.  There are far too many other things that would break.

Basically I am looking for a `URL/URI` ... thing.  Can anyone help?

This would be the best way to do it if starting from the beginning: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. The solution is as follows:

```
<a href="<?php 
$url_endpoint = get_permalink( $this->get_field('page_id.ID') );
$url_endpoint = parse_url( $url_endpoint );
$url_endpoint = $url_endpoint['path'];
echo $url_endpoint; ?>" class="button">Go to next product</a>
```

:)